# Terraform destroy doesn't execute. Gives "Destroy cancelled"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have been able to deploy AWS Auto Scaling group, load balancer, security group and EC2 instances using `terraform apply`.

Now, I want to destroy the infrastructure using command `terraform destroy`, but it gives `Destroy cancelled`.

I do not wish to destroy the resources manually from AWS Management Console but via terraform commands only.

Comment: Full error message (and at least a couple of lines of output) would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to forcefully destroy the deployed infrastructure using command `terraform destroy -force`, and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

The message "Destroy cancelled." is returned if you don't type the string "yes" at the confirmation prompt:

```
Terraform will delete all your managed infrastructure.
There is no undo. Only 'yes' will be accepted to confirm.

Do you really want to destroy?
```

Terraform requires typing `yes` as a safety measure. If you're running Terraform in a non-interactive way it may not be possible to enter this response, so the `-force` option provides a way to confirm via the command prompt.

Comment: I had typed `yes` for `Do you really want to destroy?`. It appears that there is a minimun number of times terraform tries to destroy the resources after which it aborts the operation. However , when we use the `force` switch, then it keeps on trying till the resource is deleted. In my case, it was able to delete the resource after 1min30s.

Comment: If typing `yes` still caused it to cancel, that seems like a bug in Terraform which could be reported on its github issue tracker. If you *do* report it, please be sure to state what platform you're running Terraform on since I think that might be significant here.